# Date and time format from string

Tags: python, datetime

I'm converting the date of this string in this way, but I get the error "time data 'Aug 6, 2022, 10:44 AM' does not match format '%m %d, %Y, %I:%Mp'"

```
fechaDAT = 'Aug 6, 2022, 10:44 AM'

dateC = datetime.strptime(fechaDAT, "%m %d, %Y, %I:%Mp")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the right format :

```
dateC = datetime.strptime(fechaDAT, "%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p")
```

`%b` for month abbrevation

`%p` for locale AM/PM